Why is Gnome theming broken after switching to a XFCE session?
I have both installed and I typically use GNOME, but I wanted to try something in XFCE recently, so I switched for a day and then switched back.
In the past, this has been no issue, but now, inexplicably, GNOME theming is broken. Changing the theme in the system settings from light to dark, makes no difference for most applications (including those using libadwaita.
In fact, gsd-settings crashes when I do this, along with several other applications. I can no longer get them to respect my theme settings (accent colour, dark/light mode), and I can't seem to find a solution in clearing GTK settings in .config.
Any idea what causes this, and what to do about it?

You've not provided any release, which is rather important, especially on a multi-desktop install.. eg. Ubuntu Desktop switched from GTK3/GNOME3 to GTK4/GNOME4 some releases ago, but the switch for Xfce/GTK3  to Xfce/GTK4 is always behind GNOME, and of course the toolkit being used impacts the themes (esp. with GNOME 4/GTK4 where it was radically changed!).  I'll suggest working out your release & the impacts of that (you didn't tell us so we're limited) as you likely were using older versions last time you made change(s).  I'm using a multi-desktop install here myself

@guiverc it's 24.10, but I don't think that the GTK switch is the issue.
